# Configuring eslint with JSX

Tags: reactjs, atom-editor, eslint, jsx

I cannot figure out how to configure my .eslintrc file to properly "accept" JSX. In other words, it freaks out when JSX is being typed out in Atom.

I added the `"parser": "babel-eslint"`, since that seems to be part of what other people have been doing to adjust their linters...but then I get this error in Atom:

*Error: Cannot find module 'babel-eslint' from '/Users/josetello/.atom/packages/linter-eslint/node_modules'*

I have babel-eslint installed globally and `--save-dev`. No luck. Not sure why it complains about an atom package...

Is there a better way to configure .eslintrc for JSX?

**My .eslintrc file:**

```
{
  "settings": {
   "ecmascript": 6
 },
 "ecmaFeatures": {
   "blockBindings": true,
   "jsx": true
 },
 "parser": "babel-eslint",
 "env": {
   "browser": true,
   "jquery": true,
   "node": true,
   "mocha": true,
   "es6": true
 },
 "rules": {
   "prefer-arrow-callback": 1,
   "semi": 1,
   "strict": 0,
   "indent": [2, 2],
   "quotes": [1, "single"],
   "no-multi-spaces": [1, {
     "exceptions": {
       "VariableDeclarator": true,
       "FunctionExpression": true
     }
   }],
   "key-spacing": [0, {"align": "value"}],
   "no-underscore-dangle": 0
 },
 {
  "plugins": [
      "react"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Which eslint version are you using?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Things have changed in ESLint 2 in regards to `ecmaFeatures` ([and a lot more...](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/migrating-to-2.0.0))

Instead of

```
{
    ecmaFeatures: {
        jsx: true
    }
}
```

try

```
{
    parserOptions: {
        ecmaFeatures: {
            jsx: true
        }
    }
}
```

And I think you can remove `parser`, but I don't use Atom myself, so I not going to say it for certain. It's not part of my own .eslintrc. And then you probalby want to to add the react linting rules. https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react

```
{
  "extends": ["eslint:recommended", "plugin:react/recommended"]
}
```

I like to just add all this junk to `rules` so I have quick access when I want to disable something, but maybe that's just me.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "jsx-quotes"       : 1,
    "react/display-name": 0,
    "react/forbid-prop-types": 0,
    "react/jsx-boolean-value": 1,
    "react/jsx-closing-bracket-location": 1,
    "react/jsx-curly-spacing": 1,
    "react/jsx-handler-names": 1,
    "react/jsx-indent-props": 1,
    "react/jsx-indent": 1,
    "react/jsx-key": 1,
    "react/jsx-max-props-per-line": 0,
    "react/jsx-no-bind": 0,
    "react/jsx-no-duplicate-props": 1,
    "react/jsx-no-literals": 0,
    "react/jsx-no-undef": 1,
    "react/jsx-pascal-case": 1,
    "react/jsx-sort-prop-types": 0,
    "react/jsx-sort-props": 0,
    "react/jsx-uses-react": 1,
    "react/jsx-uses-vars": 1,
    "react/no-danger": 1,
    "react/no-deprecated": 1,
    "react/no-did-mount-set-state": 1,
    "react/no-did-update-set-state": 1,
    "react/no-direct-mutation-state": 1,
    "react/no-is-mounted": 1,
    "react/no-multi-comp": 0,
    "react/no-set-state": 1,
    "react/no-string-refs": 0,
    "react/no-unknown-property": 1,
    "react/prefer-es6-class": 1,
    "react/prop-types": 1,
    "react/react-in-jsx-scope": 1,
    "react/require-extension": 1,
    "react/self-closing-comp": 1,
    "react/sort-comp": 1,
    "react/wrap-multilines": 1
  }
}
```

Comment: I really doubt it. I just upgraded eslint and a bunch of other packages in my current project last week, and it was no fun at all, but I apparently learned a couple of new tricks :)

Comment: It might help some people: You can check https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-eslint-webpack-babel/ for an ESLint setup in React, Webpack, Babel.